# nm-applet not showing until NetworkManager restart in GNOME 3

Tags: arch-linux, gnome3, networkmanager

I have recently installed Arch Linux and GNOME 3 on my new laptop and have a problem whereby **`nm-applet`** is not showing in **`gnome-panel`**, unless I manually restart the NetworkManager daemon.

Comment: I am assuming that the applet doesn't show up after login? If so, a workaround is adding **`nm-applet`** to the Startup Programs, using **`gnome-session-properties`**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer with help of the Arch Linux Forums:

I tried to start the networkmanager daemon before the dbus daemon, which does not work. Changing the order solved the problem.

Comment: how to change the order or deamons running, with systetmd?
I installed arch very recently and having the same problem, I coudn't find rc.conf to edit..

Answer (score 1):

Another way is by adding to startup apps:

```
$ gksudo "/etc/rc.d/network-manager restart"
```